# New to javascript syntax from Java

Tags: javascript, syntax, operating-system

I am working on detecting OS version using javascript. I have an understanding of Java but some Javascript syntax is just confusing like this one below:

```
    var os = (function() {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        return {
            isWin2K: /windows nt 5.0/.test(ua),
            isXP: /windows nt 5.1/.test(ua),
            isVista: /windows nt 6.0/.test(ua),
            isWin7: /windows nt 6.1/.test(ua)
        };
    }());
```

I am not sure why we have colons : in the return statement and what exactly are they doing.

Also what is the purpose of / / and the text in between?

Is it returning a boolean? or a String?

Also, why do we have

```
     }());
```

in the end?

I would just type

```
    }
```

instead
Thank you for taking your time to read through. I know this code works for me but I would like to learn why.

Thanks.

Comment: Clues: Javascript object, regex, immediate functions.

Answer (score 3):

> I am not sure why we have colons : in the return statement

The right hand side of the return statement is [an *object literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals). The colons separate the property name (on the left) from the value (on the right).

> Also what is the purpose of / / and the text in between?

Those are [regular expression literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression).

> Is it returning a boolean? or a String?

Neither, it is returning an Object.

> Also, why do we have `}()`

This is an immediately invoked function. `os` is the return value of the function, not the function itself.

In this example, it allows the `ua` variable to be used in a local scope.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the term "Object literal" and I can read more about it. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns an object with 4 properties (isWin2K, isXP, etc), each of them having a boolean value. You can use it like this:

```
if (os.isXP) {
  // Windows XP specific code
}
```

The colon is part of the syntax of declaring an object literal:

```
var a = { prop1 : val1, prop2 : val2 };
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals

The thing that looks like a string but is between / instead of ' or " is called a literal RegExp.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Finally, all the useful code there is wrapped in an Immediately Invoked Functional Expression (IIFE). It is a common structure used in JavaScript to prevent the pollution of a scope (usually the global scope) with variables. As you will soon learn, JavaScript has function scope, so if you want to isolate some variables and have them "local" you need to wrap them in a function. The IIFE does just that, but it is also called immediately, so the instructions are executed on that spot, just like if the wrapper function didn't exist:

```
var b = 10;
a = b + 5;
```

is equivalent to

```
(function() {
var b = 10;
a = b + 5;
}) ();
```

except that the second sollution doesn't introduce the b variable in the outer scope.

Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure why we have colons : in the return statement and what exactly are they doing.

In your given code, the `return {r:val}` is actually returning an object. In Javascript:

```
var obj = {
    r: 'some value',
    t: 'some other value'
};
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.r = 'some value';
obj.t = 'some other value';
```

so the following portion of your code:

```
return {
            isWin2K: /windows nt 5.0/.test(ua),
            isXP: /windows nt 5.1/.test(ua),
            isVista: /windows nt 6.0/.test(ua),
            isWin7: /windows nt 6.1/.test(ua)
        };
```

is actually returning an object as described with the above example. let us now replace `return {r:val}` with `return obj`. so your given function have the form:

```
var os = ( function() 
                     { 
                       return obj 
                     }());
```

now study about javascript function a little. [This page](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsFunc/index.html) will give you a very good insight for javascript function.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I am returning four booleans in that return statement.

Comment: four booleans! Nope, you are returning an object with four fields. Reread the example.